# Are vibronic coherences, vibrational coherences and electronic coherences types of quantum coherence or classical coherence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, biophysics

I am doing a research project on whether quantum coherence is involved in how light energy is transferred after the initial absorption of light during photosynthesis. I have found a research paper that discusses wether vibronic coherences, vibrational coherences, electronic coherences or no coherences are involved in this process. However, I do not know wether these types of coherence are quantum or classical.

Also, I am not entirely sure what vibrational coherence is. From my research, I gather that vibrational coherence results from superposition between either excited or ground-state vibrational states. But is this refering to vibrational states of the nucleus or of electrons or either?

Also, I am unsure what vibronic coherence is. From my research, I have found that vibronic coupling is the interaction between electronic and nuclear vibrational motion and that vibronic coherence is coherence between excited vibronic states. So is vibronic coherence coherence between separate nuclear and electronic states or coherence between mixed nuclear and electronic states which cannot be separated out into separate nuclear and electronic states?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a link to the research paper.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I do not know wether these types of coherence are quantum or classical.

All of your examples are types of quantum coherence.

> Also, I am not entirely sure what vibrational coherence is. From my research, I gather that vibrational coherence results from superposition between either excited or ground-state vibrational states. But is this refering to vibrational states of the nucleus or of electrons or either?

It refers to nuclear motion only. The electrons follow the nuclei, as they are much lighter and therefore much faster, but they are often delocalized over the entire molecule. When we talk about vibrational motion, we focus mostly on the nuclei, as they move in the potential-energy surface created by the electrostatic interaction with the electrons once the electrons' motion has been averaged out. (For a place to b start reading, look for the Born-Oppenheimer approximation.)

> So is vibronic coherence coherence between separate nuclear and electronic states or coherence between mixed nuclear and electronic states which cannot be separated out into separate nuclear and electronic states?

The latter. We talk about vibronic states when the Born-Oppenheimer separation between nuclear and electronic motion fails, and we need to consider both motions on a couple and equal footing.